# Using a Wildcard in Postman API Call

Tags: api, postman

I am trying to perform a GET API call in Postman.
One of the parameters in the query (a string) should include a wildcard, since I want to receive response which includes several optional values (for example "Demo1...", "Demo2...").

Any suggestion how this can be done?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.